# Shortest path in Neo4j that must pass through some services represented by nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, dijkstra, shortest-path

The problem is as follows:

I would like to find shortest path between two Hosts (Ha,Hb) in a network, the path should pass some functions (f1,f2,f3,...fn) where some nodes are hosting some of those.(node1 hosts f1,f2  node14 hosts f4, etc,,,).

The problem can't be solved by running Dijkstra's on sub levels (Ha to node1, node1 to nodek, nodek to Hb) because we may choose the shortest path in the first which yields in high cost in last path parts.

How can I do it using Cypher? any Graph algorithms handle such stuff.

The input (start host, end host, list functions, list of nodes with corresponding hosted functions)

Please consider that passing the function could be in order and could be not.

example:
src host in city A  and dst is in a city B
functions: firewall, loadbalancer
nodes that hosts functions: firewall service is hosted in Node 1,3,4,5 Loadbalancer hosted in Node 2,3,6,7.

each edge and process has its own cost.
Order of who should be first could be ON or OFF based of what we can solve now and other case could be handled later.

at the end: path should looks
CityA---pathcost=3---Node4 Firewall(process cost =1)---pathcost=2---Node6 loadbanacer(process cost=2)---pathcost=2---CityB
thanx

Comment: What do you mean by functions? Example input?

Comment: I add one example, I hope it is better now @stdob--

Comment: How are you representing these 'functions'? As labels on the associated nodes? As properties?

Comment: For me I would use properties. However, I will consider all variations to address and solve the problem. @InverseFalcon